# Interpretation of several I(1) variables ADL regression

Tags: time-series, interpretation, regression-coefficients, stationarity, autoregressive

I see a lot of weird interpretation of coefficients, when working with a time-series model with two (or more) variables. Specifically I am thinking of two series that are I(1) and are then log-diffed to achieve stationarity. Wouldn't the correct interpretation of the coefficient of one variable on the other, $x$, be "the effect - in percentage points - of changing *the growth rate* of the independent variable 1 percentage point on the dependent variable growth rate"?

To clarify, the regression framework would be something like
$$ \Delta \log(y_t) = a + b \Delta \log(x_t) + \dots + \epsilon_t $$

where I am thinking of the interpretation of $b$.

Comment: Title says I(2), body says I(1). Which one is it?

Comment: @RichardHardy, thanks for letting me know. Title changed.